# Undefined variable when Uploading a file to Google Drive

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Hi i have an issue  when i call [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) using the [PHP Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

my coding is

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle($title);
$result = $service->files->insert($file, array(
'data' => file_get_contents("dd.doc"),
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```

I got the following errors

> Undefined variable: service  Trying to get property of non-object 
>   Call to a member function insert()

Comment: Where is the $service initialization part?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the client lib in your script?  or did you just forget to add that part?

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';     
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
```

Also check that $service was created properly.  you are missing that code.

```
$client_id = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
$client_secret = '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>';
$redirect_uri = '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

A very good example can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simplefileupload.php)

Comment: where are you creating $service,  you should really post all of your code there isn't enough there to help you.

Comment: i have initialize now but i got error like Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error